# Should I provide Sync or Async methods for developers in my IMDB API library?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, asynchronous

I'm going to make a DLL Library that'll alow developers to search and access IMDB movie pages.

How should I handle the freezing in the GUI, should I use async methods, or should I allow a dev to manually create a thread for using our DLL?

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely up to you.

That being said, I think providing an asynchronous and a synchronous API will make your library act more like the framework libraries, which will give your users the best chance of using it correctly.

For example, WebClient provides [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) and [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync.aspx).  I would, personally, mimic this behavior in my API.  If you implement your library asynchronously, it's very easy to wrap this in a synchronous API.

Answer (score 1):

This is a judgement call on your end.  Consider, however:

1. The user can always use a `BackgroundWorker` to avoid blocking, if you only expose in a synchronous way.
2. If you feel that you can provide some intermediary data during the action (like progress percentage) then an asynchronous version may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid asynchronous calls within a library like this.

What if the user of the library doesn't care about blocking? What if it's a command-line script that *should* block?

The threading of an application is a major design decision, avoid making for them.

I would first implement the blocking, synchronous calls and perhaps later, add asynchronous methods to make the library easier to use for thread-shy programmers.