# How can I provide asynchronous methods for other developers?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

For now, my library [CherryTomato](https://github.com/sergiotapia/CherryTomato) is where I want it to be, and now I'd like to provide asynchronous methods for other devs to use.

Currently here's how they can use it:

```
string apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"];

//A Tomato is the main object that will allow you to access RottenTomatoes information.
//Be sure to provide it with your API key in String format.
var tomato = new Tomato(apiKey);

//Finding a movie by it's RottenTomatoes internal ID number.
Movie movie = tomato.FindMovieById(9818);

//The Movie object, contains all sorts of goodies you might want to know about a movie.
Console.WriteLine(movie.Title);
Console.WriteLine(movie.Year);
```

What can I use to provide asynchronous methods? Ideally I'd like to fire the loading, and let the devs listen for an event to fire and when it fires they can then use the fully loaded information.

Here is the code for FindMovieById:

```
public Movie FindMovieById(int movieId)
{
    var url = String.Format(MOVIE_INDIVIDUAL_INFORMATION, ApiKey, movieId);
    var jsonResponse = GetJsonResponse(url);
    return Parser.ParseMovie(jsonResponse);
}

private static string GetJsonResponse(string url)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's all a judgement call, but I'd spend that time doing other things, like testing my library to ensure that it was safe to call from multiple threads.  The user can always add their own asynchronous wrapper.  That is, unless you can provide a way to track progress, in which case the user would see a real benefit from using your library's async implementation.  See answers to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663871/should-i-provide-sync-or-async-methods-for-developers-in-my-imdb-api-library

Comment: @Merlyn: Your suggestions of allowing developers to wrap the process in asynchronous makes sense. Hm... I didn't expect this shade of gray to come forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the standard way to handle this is using the AsyncResult pattern.  It is used throughout the .net platform take a look at this msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for some more info.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4, you might also consider using `IObservable<>` to be used with the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896). For starters, grab WebClientExtensions from [here](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/07/developing-with-rx-part-2-converting.html). Your implementation is then pretty similar:

```
public IObservable<Movie> FindMovieById(int movieId)
{
    var url = String.Format(MOVIE_INDIVIDUAL_INFORMATION, ApiKey, movieId);
    var jsonResponse = GetJsonResponse(url);
    return jsonResponse.Select(r => Parser.ParseMovie(r));
}

private static IObservable<string> GetJsonResponse(string url)
{
    return Observable.Using(() => new WebClient(),
        client => client.GetDownloadString(url));
}
```

Comment: I suppose Rx is available for .NET 3.5, Silverlight 3+ and Windows Phone 7 as well, so this doesn't just work in .NET 4.